# changing keyboard languages by shortcut keys

Tags: shortcut-keys, 15.10, input-language

In 15.10 everything works fine with the default super+space but when I change it to alt+shift I can change the language from english to the second one but when I press alt+shift again it doesn't work and stays in the second language. and sometimes for setting the alt+shift as a shortcut key it doesn't even recognize these button and recognize them as a different button! and I have to re-open the text entry setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>and it works find for changing to the second language and returning to the original one.  But as I changed it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>, It just worked as you described.

Generally, it is advised to avoid <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for this purpose since these keys are being used in some other apps as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd>.

I also suggest getting used to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.